# Pdf of the radius of a 2D Gaussian for a fixed angle

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-probability, density-function, fake-proofs

The 2D Gaussian distribution is known for its rotational symmetry (as shown in this [3blue1brown video](https://youtu.be/cy8r7WSuT1I?t=814)), and it's also known that the radius $R = \sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}$ in polar coordinates follows a [Rayleigh distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution). Let me try to put these valid facts against each other towards a contradiction:

Consider $p(R\mid\theta)$ for a given $\theta\in(-\pi,\pi)$. From the rotational symmetry, we know that if we rotate the bell, we still get the normal distribution, so the radius, which is constrained to be positive, must follow a [half-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution). For instance, if $\theta=0$, we would be considering the distribution of the radius $R$ constrained to the positive x axis, which is basically $X|Y=0,X>0$. However, we know that the radius $R$ follows a Rayleigh distribution regardless of the angle, not a half-normal. Absurd.

Where is the flaw in this argument and why isn't it so obvious?

Comment: In polar coordinates, you have to correct the element of area with the jacobian $r$. Indeed, the Rayleigh distribution is roughly a half-normal multiplied by $r$.

Comment: Actually, when conditioning in an event of probability $0$, one must be very careful, because the probability depends on the underlying $\sigma$-algebra, and you have different $\sigma$-algebras for each case.

Comment: To see that, you can condition over an event of probability different than $0$. For example, $\theta \in (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ is quite different from $X\in(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ for any $\epsilon>0$.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4769767/polar-transformation-of-joint-uniform-and-normal-probability-distribution), and the solution is yet another example of [Borel's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_paradox). The conditional probability $P_{XY|\Theta}(x, y | \theta)$ is a half-normal distribution within some Cartesian strip, but the conditional probability $P_{R|\Theta}(r, \theta)$ is a Rayleigh distribution within some wedge of $\theta$.